# Web Api 2 call from axios

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api2, axios

When I make a call to web api 2 from axios, the HttpPostedFileaBase is coming in as null.  I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Upload(Config config)
    {
        //config.Name has value
        //config.File is null

    }
```

Here is the axios call:

```
const data = {
        Name:'john',
        File: event.target.files[0] //this has value here
    }


const config = { headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/api/upload',
        data: data,
        config
    })
        .then((response) => {
            })
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I can see the file when I `console.log`, but when it gets to the api call, it is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should append your file to formdata.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file',file)
```

then

```
axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/api/upload',
        data: formData,
        config
})
```

Comment: I was doing this before, but if I want to add other stuff from the form, do I have to do `formData.append('form-prop','form-value')` for each one

Comment: Yeah, but you can encapsulate them into one object `formData.append('body',{})`